# @Around advice with Controller is not working

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am trying to log controller methods using AOP in Spring boot application (with Spring security) and Couldn't able to make it out. It's not returning any exception and handler method is not able to detect after adding aspect related code:

**Controller method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView welcome() {
    ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
    modelView.setViewName("index");
    return modelView;
}
```

Aspect:

```
@Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping *)")
    public void requestMapping() {}

    @Around("execution(* com.hms.controllers.HomeController.*(..)) && @annotation(requestMapping)")
    public void aroundControllerMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, RequestMapping requestMapping) {
        System.out.println("Testing aroundController: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
}
```

**Failing with below logs:**

```
2015-11-18 12:57:41.310 DEBUG 6180 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /index
2015-11-18 12:57:41.310 DEBUG 6180 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/index]
```

If Aspect related code commented, index page returning without any issue

Any insight?

Answer (score 0):

Controllers are already proxied by spring mvc and may be the around advice is not installed. I had the same problem years ago and resolved it shortly using a logging filter. You can also define an HandlerInterceptor

Comment: will Before or After advices works with Controllers??

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I did a tentative with bad results and since that time I keep using filters or interceptors that are mechanism well suited for intercepting requests based on URI mapping. Here a nice post on interceptors. http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter